# Include in EF Core 2.0 create infinite nested child Entities

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have 2 entities with a **One-to-One relationship**, the models are:

```
public class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TrackingDevice TrackingDevice { get; set; }
}

public class TrackingDevice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public int? AssetId { get; set; }
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

I have entered data so when I make a simple query as follows:

```
var list = _appContext.TrackingDevices.Include(td => td.Asset).ToListAsync();
```

I get correctly the list of tracking devices that include their asset, however, the asset child again includes the tracking device, and this in turn the asset and so on, which creates an infinite structure that when applying the `AutoMapper` failure.

How can I do the Include and only get the 2 levels I need?
Tracking Device -> Asset

Comment: Are you using lazy loading?

Comment: No sé que es Lazy loading en C#, ¿Qué debo hacer para arreglar mi problema?

Comment: This is how EF works. There is nothing you can do at EF side. But AutoMapper (depending on which version you are using) has options for handling reference loops.

Answer (score 1):

This is really annoying in EF Core. 
 
I could not solve it completely but **here is a wrok-around about that Not a complete solution**

```
var list = _appContext.TrackingDevices.Include(td => td.Asset).ToListAsync();
foreach(var l in list)
   l.Asset.TrackingDevice = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to build is a 1-to-1 relationship between your Asset and your Tracking device.
Your code, if not configured properly, really tells EF Core that each of you entity have an entity linked to it.

To make EF Core understand that, this is how you need to declare your relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
        .HasOne(a => a.TrackingDevice)
        .WithOne(t => t.Asset)
        .HasForeignKey<TrackingDevice>(b => b.AssetId);
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration) to get more information on how to set this up.

Additionally, to avoid having EF to avoid returning nested objects, try to use [Select](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/querying-data#returning-non-entity-types) instead of include (you can then export exactly what you need):

```
var list = _appContext.TrackingDevices
     .Select(t => new {
         TrackingDevice = t,
         ...
         Asset = Asset,
     });
```

Comment: I have it defined that way in the ApplicationDbContext, Before I had it defined like this (and it worked): builder.Entity <TrackingDevice> ().HasOne(t => t.Asset).WithMany().HasForeignKey (a => a.AssetId); But I really need One-to-one

Comment: HasOne(t => t.Asset).WithMany() builds a one-to many relationship, .HasOne(a => a.TrackingDevice).WithOne(t => t.Asset) does it as one-to-one

Comment: I understand the relationships, but I dont understand why the INCLUDE doesnt work whit One-to-One and works with one-to-many... The problem is, why I get a nested infinite entities?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I know about Select, but I dont want use it because I have a lot of properties and the models can change and I dont want change the query too, for this reason I want to use INCLUDE. If I dont use Include, just _appContext.TrackingDevices.ToListAsync() I get the list but the property Asset is null, if I put .Include(td => td.Asset) I get a infinite nested structure..

Comment: Did you disable [LazyLoading](https://ardalis.com/avoid-lazy-loading-entities-in-asp-net-applications) from your project?

Comment: I think that I dont need disable that because I dont know what is that, the people say enable/disable LazyLoading but I really dont know what origin the problem... Have you had this problem using include and One-to-One relationships?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185080/discussion-between-benjamin-soulier-and-juan-calderon).